# How to specify a dependency of an Angular component by its consuming module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a Component (It happens to be a Calendar that wraps FullCalendar) that will be used by three similar modules.  Each module has a corresponding service that provides event management (get, push, post and  delete of calendar events).  Dependant on the Consumer of the Calendar Component, I need to have it use the corresponding service. All my googling has only turned up examples where dependency injection can be determined (with a factory) at run time in the providers array, but I have not found anything for when it is  dependant on the consuming module. I just expected that I would have to have all the services extend from an abstract class in order to help this to work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share some code, but I guess you can just define a common interface for the three services and than provide the specific class in each module: `{ provide: CommonInterface, useClass: ImplementationClass }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes.

In Angular a component will traverse up the tree (up to the root) to find the first possible provider of a class (or injection token).

So, if your "wrapping" components (or modules, or whatever up the tree) provides that service, your "inner" calendar can inject it.

One caveat is that you provide the abstract class, but using other class, e.g.

```
export class MyAbstractService {
}

@Injectable()
export class ConcreteImplementation1 extends MyAbstractService {
}

@Injectable()
export class ConcreteImplementation2 extends MyAbstractService {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'wrapper-1',
    templateUrl: 'wrapper-1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./wrapper-1.component.scss'],
    providers: [{ provide: MyAbstractService, useClass: ConcreteImplementation1 }]
})
export class Wrapper1Component {    
}

@Component({
    selector: 'wrapper-2',
    templateUrl: 'wrapper-2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./wrapper-2.component.scss'],
    providers: [{ provide: MyAbstractService, useClass: ConcreteImplementation2 }]
})
export class Wrapper2Component {    
}



@Component({
    selector: 'calendar',
    templateUrl: 'calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss'],
})
export class Wrapper2Component {
    constructor(private readonly myService: MyAbstractService) {
        // Will be ConcreteImplementation1 inside wrapper1
        // and ConcreteImplementation2 inside wrapper2
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the slight typing error where TotallyNewb typed "[{ provide: AbstractService,.". instead of "[{ provide: MyAbstractService,..."  It works perfectly.  Helped my understanding of how providers are used as well.   Thanks TotallyNewb.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! Was typing from the top of my head and didn't paste it into any decent editor. Updated the answer with a fix for the typos.